# empty gap between JPanel in Borderlayout

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, border

i am trying to add empty gap between two JPanel, i tried to add the border like this `mypanel.setBorder(createEmptyBorder(0, 0, 3, 0));` but in the same time i have created a using the method `createBevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED` so i am losing the second Border because of the first

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In swing, you can create a [compound border](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/BorderFactory.html#createCompoundBorder%28javax.swing.border.Border,%20javax.swing.border.Border%29). Using this you could have the bevel border as the inner one and the empty border as the outer one on your JPanel.

As as example:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(
    BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 0, 3, 0),
    BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED));
```

Check out the tutorials on borders in the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html).

Comment: give more ditels please

Comment: Nice answer, especially with the links to both documentation and tutorial. :)

Answer (score 0):

your answer is good but it miss a lot of information this is the right answer from the doc you give me thank you after all

```
 Border Campound,empty,Boveld;

            empty = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(60, 5, 5, 5);
            Boveld = BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED);
            Campound = BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(empty,Boveld);

        JPanel textFiled = new JPanel(); 
                textFiled.setBorder(Campound);
```

Comment: *"it miss a lot of information"*  Many times people give answers that expect you to look up the classes and methods, and read the documentation, by yourself.  As programmers we need to read a *lot* of documentation, and it is not usually worth repeating it here.  For that reason I urge you to accept the answer of jakson.